# Azure - App Availability percentage is Zero

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

our Api app is in UAT on Azure with service plan (Standard 3 large). What should we do if App Availability is Zero. It is getting slow response or timeout issue. When i restart the application it is up to normal. (We are using Parallel Language programming.(Async/Await)

How to find the route cause from it for slowness issue.

[image]

Comment: This is not enough information to tell. Try including more information on how the app is hosted and configured, as well as the average load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that Always On feature is enabled.

Such problems may be caused by application level issues, such as:

network requests taking a long time
application code or database queries being inefficient
application using high memory/CPU
application crashing due to an exception

You could enable web server diagnostics to fetch more details on the issue.

Detailed Error Logging - Detailed error information for HTTP status codes that indicate a failure (status code 400 or greater). This may contain information that can help determine why the server returned the error code.

Failed Request Tracing - Detailed information on failed requests, including a trace of the IIS components used to process the request and the time taken in each component. This can be useful if you are attempting to improve web app performance or isolate what is causing a specific HTTP error.

Web Server Logging - Information about HTTP transactions using the W3C extended log file format. This is useful when determining overall web app metrics, such as the number of requests handled or how many requests are from a specific IP address.

Also, Azure Application Insights collects telemetry from your application to help analyze its operation and performance. You can use this information to identify problems that may be occurring or to identify improvements to the application that would most impact users. This tutorial takes you through the process of analyzing the performance of both the server components of your application and the perspective of the client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-performance

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation